# If element is inside a list not working properly in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like:

```
readFile = [['String1'], [], ['String2'], []]
stringList = ['String1','String2']
```

However, after using Python's if statement:

```
for value in stringList:
  if not value in readStocksFile:
    print(value+" does not exist in this list")
```

According to Python, the value String1 isn't inside my readFile list which isn't true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "the value String1 isn't inside my readFile list which isn't true" - it *is* true. `readFile` has 4 elements and none of those are `'String1'`.

Comment: To be more specific, `'String1' != ['String1']`. You need to check each sublist in the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the check as "Is this string in a list of list of strings", then I would use the any method:

```
readFile = [['String1'], [], ['String2'], []]
stringList = ['String1','String2']

for value in stringList:
    if not any(value in sublist for sublist in readFile):
        print(value + " does not exist in this list")
```

The line `if not any(value in file for file in readFile)` means: if there is not a single case where `value` is in one of the `sublist`, then do the print.

Answer (score 1):

because is a list inside a list

```
readFile = [['String1'], [], ['String2'], []]
```

try this

```
readFile = ['String1','' , 'String2', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `String1` is of data type string and `['String1']` is of data-type List , Hence `String1` is shown not in `readFile`. For `String1` to be in `readFile` , `readFile` should be:

```py
readFile = ['String1', '', 'String2', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not work because the in readFile there are no string values, instead there are more lists which have string values so one way of correcting it would be:

```
if not [value] in readFile
```

because the value is "String1" so the if statement becomes `if not ['String1'] in readFile`
and readFile has the following elements: `["String1"]`, `[]`, `["String2"]`
so since `["String1"]` is in the readFile list the if statement would not get triggered.